# Problems with AddForce in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I have been working on this 2D project that's my first game ever. I have a player object and I have been trying to make a dash for it, but I can't get AddForce to work in the player object and I also can't find other ways of doing it that doesn't depend on fps. Where is the dash code and the player's settings.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (isDashing || isHammering || PauseMenu.isPaused)
    {
        return;
    }
    

    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    if (Mathf.Approximately(horizontalInput, 0f) && isGrounded())
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(0f, body.velocity.y);
    }

    //Rotate player sprite when moving
    if (horizontalInput > 0.01f)
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    else if (horizontalInput < -0.01F)
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1,1,1);

    //dash
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && canDash && !onWall())
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(0, body.velocity.y);
        StartCoroutine(Dash());
    }
    //hammer
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !onWall() && hammerCooldown<hammercooldownTimer)
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(0f, body.velocity.y);
        isHammering = true;
        anim.SetTrigger("hammer");
        hammercooldownTimer = 0;
    }
    hammercooldownTimer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (wallJumpCooldown > 0.2f && !isHammering)
    {
        //MOVE
        if(isGrounded()) anim.ResetTrigger("jump");
        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * speed, body.velocity.y);

        //Wall jump
        if (onWall() && !isGrounded())
        {
            body.gravityScale = 0;
            body.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            
        }
        else
            body.gravityScale = 1.5f;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            Jump();
    }
    else
        wallJumpCooldown += Time.deltaTime;

    //Set animator parameters
    anim.SetBool("run", horizontalInput != 0 && !isHammering);
    anim.SetBool("grounded", isGrounded());
    anim.SetBool("wall", onWall());
}
private IEnumerator Dash()
{
    canDash = false;
    isDashing = true;
    float originalGravity = body.gravityScale;
    body.gravityScale = 0f;
    body.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    anim.SetTrigger("dash");

    
    playerHealth.isInvulnerable = true;
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 7, true);


    //float startTime = Time.time; 
    //while (Time.time < startTime + dashingTime)
    //{

    //    Vector2 pos = body.position;
    //    if (transform.localScale.x > 0f)
    //        pos += new Vector2(1 * dashingPower, 0.0f);
    //    else
    //        pos += new Vector2(-1 * dashingPower, 0.0f);

    //    body.MovePosition(pos);

    //    yield return null; 
    //}
    Debug.Log(body.velocity);
    Vector2 distance = new Vector2(dashingPower, 0);
    if (transform.localScale.x > 0f)
        distance = new Vector2(dashingPower, 0.0f);
    else
        distance = new Vector2(-dashingPower, 0.0f);
    Debug.Log(distance);
    body.drag = 0f;
    body.AddForce(distance, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    Debug.Log(distance);
    Debug.Log(body.velocity);
    
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 7, false);
    playerHealth.isInvulnerable = false;




    body.gravityScale = originalGravity;
    isDashing = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingCooldown);
    canDash = true;

}
```

[image: Player Material]
[image: Player RigidBody2D]

Notes: The problem is really with the AddForce because if I instead use the commented code it works, but that way depends on the frames per second, so I wanted to change it. I debug it already and I can see that the speed is changed after addForce but it doesn´t move.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the direction in your commented code with `Time.deltaTime` to make it **framerate-independent**.
This will do the trick:

```
Vector2 pos = body.position;
if (transform.localScale.x > 0f)
    pos += new Vector2(1 * dashingPower, 0.0f) * Time.deltaTime;
else
    pos += new Vector2(-1 * dashingPower, 0.0f) * Time.deltaTime;

body.MovePosition(pos);
```

Comment: thank you very much but I keep ondering why the addForce doesnt work here